Reproducing Apple’s Journal App List UI & Swipe Animations
I'm struggling to recreate the UI of Apple's Journal app. The List in the Journal app has each element as an independent entity, and the swipe animations for deletion and editing are unlike anything I've seen before.
Apple Journal App
To replicate this, I attempted the following code, which seems to work initially. However, when I swipe to delete, a red area with mismatched sizing appears due to the plain List style.
my case
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = Array(0...5)
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(String(item))
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing){
                    Button(role: .destructive) { print("delete action.") } label: { Image(systemName: "trash.fill") }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}


Does anyone have ideas or suggestions on how to recreate a List similar to the Journal app using SwiftUI or UIKit? Additionally, does anyone know how Apple might have implemented this?
Any comments, even minor ones, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Can you please provide a simplified reproducible code that can be copied and pasted elsewhere for testing? The current code provided is not reproducible. Also you mentioned mismatched sizing due to plain list style. If you change the list style, does the sizing change?

Thank you for the report. I have revised the reproducible code to make it more concise and suitable for copy and paste. I also updated the ‘my case’ images.

I haven’t been able to replicate the round action buttons when swiping, but I solved the issue of aligning the swipe action buttons properly.
Previously, in a List using Section, when deleting items, the section height would remain. However, by using the listRowSpacing API, I was able to achieve a cleaner look and proper deletion behavior.
Below is the code that mimics a journal app for reference:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = Array(0...5)
    let topColor = Color(red: 247/255, green: 245/255, blue: 246/255)
    let bottomColor = Color(red: 243/255, green: 238/255, blue: 245/255)
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(String(item))
                    .padding()
                    .listRowBackground(Color.white)
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                Button(role: .destructive) { print("delete") } label: { Image(systemName: "trash.fill") }
                Button { print("edit") } label: { Image(systemName: "pencil") }
                    .tint(.indigo)
            }
        }
        .listRowSpacing(20)
        .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.2), radius: 8)
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .background(LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                .init(color: self.topColor, location: 0.3),
                .init(color: self.bottomColor, location: 1.0)
            ]),
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom
        ))
    }
}

DemoImage
If anyone has insights on how to achieve the round action buttons when swiping, please leave a comment!

You can display a round icon instead of a square button:

Set a clear tint for the button
Change the symbol variant to show in a circle instead
Use a two-color foreground style for the symbol

Button {
    print("edit")
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill") // <- use a circle variant for the symbol
        .foregroundStyle(.white, .indigo) // <- use two colors for the foregroundStyle
    }
.tint(.clear) // <- set clear tint for the button

Optionally, you can display an icon and text, by using a label and increasing the available space for each row.
Here are the two ways described, based on the code you provided:
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(String(item))
            .padding(.vertical, 30)
            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
    }
    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
        Button(role: .destructive) {
            print("delete")
        } label: {
            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
        }
        
        Button {
            print("edit")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill") // <- use a circle variant for the symbol
                .foregroundStyle(.white, .indigo) // <- use two colors for the foregroundStyle
        }
        .tint(.clear) // <- set clear tint for the button
    }
}


I can't seem to find a way to change the size of the icon or the spacing between the buttons.
Any further customizations will probably require a custom swipe gesture to give you full control over the buttons shown.

Oh, thank you for the useful information! It might be difficult to achieve the same look as a journal app using SwiftUI’s List…
